# Listen to Stripe Webhooks using Firebase Functions and Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I've been trying to listen to Stripe webhooks with firebase functions.
here is my code:

```
exports.stripeEvents = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => 
{
  try
  {    
    const stripesignature = request.headers['stripe-signature'] as string;
    let stripeevent:Stripe.Event;
    try 
    {
      stripeevent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, stripesignature, config.stripewebhooksecretkey);
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
      sentry.captureException(error);  
      response.status(400).end();
      return;
    } 
    
    response.sendStatus(200);
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    sentry.captureException(error);
    throw error;
  }
});
```

and I keep getting this error:

> No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload.
> Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

I have tried changing `request.rawBody` to `request.rawBody.toString()` but of no avail. The same firebase function works perfectly when I do a test webhook run from the stripe website.
What could I be missing?

Stripe official documentation on how to do it: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures

[image]

Comment: Likely culprit is a mismatch in webhook signing secrets. Since a test webhook from the Stripe dashboard works as expected it means your code is correct. Do you perhaps have multiple accounts or are creating events with a live key which then get sent to a test mode endpoint?

Comment: Thank you @PaulAsjes. I have double confirmed that I am using the test mode and passing the webhook=>signing secret when constructEvent. I was finally able to make it work by recreating the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an immediate solution, but here are a few suggestions to try:

1. Check whether changing `const stripesignature` to a variable produces different behaviour
2. Log the values of all 3 inputs immediately before that line, then inspect to determine if they are as anticipated (or a substring of each instead, for the more security-minded)

See if you can narrow it down to which input is causing the issue (e.g. request.rawBody, or stripesignature).

On the other hand, although an incorrect webhook secret would be expected to produce a different error, there may be little harm checking it is propagating correctly from config and matching the one in the configured endpoint setting in the dashboard.

Comment: Thank you @ed2 for your input, I was finally able to make it work by recreating the webhook.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear @AjitGoel